# rxjs sequential dynamic number of api calls

Tags: rxjs

Trying to create an rxjs pipeline that will do the following:
Essentially I have an array of a dynamic number of API calls. Every time I need to make a new API call,  I push it to the array.

Then, I transform the array into an array of RXJS switchmap operators. (The sequence of the calls doesn't matter, just that I need to make one call after the previous call finishes, and not at the same time).

Finally, I try to spread the array of rxjs operators inside a pipe:

```
const obsArray = [randomQuote(), getCatFacts(4), recipeSearch('oil')]
const OperatorWrap = obsArray.map((obs) => {
  return rxops.switchMap((val) => { return obs })
})



const pipeline= of(1).pipe(...OperatorWrap);
```

But I get a strange error message:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`concatAll` it is what do you need

> `concatAll` - Collect observables and subscribe to next when previous completes.

I did an example:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-jy2gda?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
    const APIs = [
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`,
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2`,
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3`,
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/4`
    ].map(url => this.http.get(url));
    from(APIs)
      .pipe(concatAll())
      .subscribe();
```

[image]

Comment: `from(APIs).pipe(concatAll())` is turning an array into a stream, then storing the values of the stream in an array. You can do this without `from`. `from(APIs).pipe(concatAll())`  is the same as `concat(APIs)` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

#### `merge`: run the array of observables in parallel, emit results one at a time as they arrive:

We'll log the results to the console.

```
const obsArray = [randomQuote(), getCatFacts(4), recipeSearch('oil')];
merge(...obsArray).subscribe(console.log);
```

#### `forkJoin`: run the array of observables in parallel, emit results as an array

The array is actually the final value emitted by each observable. This means they must all emit > 0 values and must all complete. Often used for HTTP GET requests.

```
const obsArray = [randomQuote(), getCatFacts(4), recipeSearch('oil')];
forkJoin(obsArray).subscribe(console.log);
```

#### `concat`: Run the array of observables in order

Wait for `obsArray[0]` to complete before starting `obsArray[1]` and so on...

```
const obsArray = [randomQuote(), getCatFacts(4), recipeSearch('oil')];
concat(...obsArray).subscribe(console.log);
```

#### Array of operators

This should work pretty much like `concat`, though the situations where it's really recommended/required are slim and far between. Use `concat` instead.

The way `pipe` is implemented is meant to give typescript a way to check that the types match up throughout your functional composition. The downside is that it doesn't seem to behave well with the spread operator. I'm pretty sure it's safe to ignore this TS error.

GitHub: [.pipe fn type overloads no longer support using spread arguments #3989](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3989)

```
const obsArray = [randomQuote(), getCatFacts(4), recipeSearch('oil')];
const operatorFunctions = obsArray.map(obs => rxops.switchMap(_ => obs));

const pipeline = of(1).pipe(
  // @ts-ignore
  ...operatorFunctions
);
```